# Use other stylesheet instead of App_Themes

Tags: html, asp.net, css, .net-4.0, stylesheet

I have an ASP website that is using `App_Themes` in the project.

Inside this website, I have merged another colleague's work who has been working on `/colleague_work/`. The new work has new styles independent of the App_Themes, namely `/colleague_work/styles.css`.

When I view the source of the site at `/colleague_work/default.aspx`, the `App_Theme/Theme1/AppStyles.css` is being injected to the page and is overwriting styles.

How do I swap the stylesheets, or disable the first stylesheet, without upsetting the rest of the website's styling from App_Themes? The colleague's stylesheets are not allowed to be moved from their location into the App_Themes folder.

File tree structure:

[image: File tree structure example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `ASP.NET`, attributes and elements take precedence in the following order (first to last):

1. Theme attributes in the `@ Page` directive
2. `<pages theme="themeName">` elements in the `<system.web>` section of a `web.config` file
3. Local control attributes
4. `StyleSheetTheme` attributes in the `@ Page` directive
5. `<pages styleSheetTheme="themeName">` elements in a `web.config` file

One workaround would be to disable the themes for a specific page, by setting the `EnableTheming` attribute of the `@ Page` directive to false, while also referencing the `styles.css` with a `<link>` tag.

This is done before the `<!DOCUTYPE>` tag, and for the `/colleague_work/default.aspx` page, would look something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableTheming="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
...
</html>
```

**More information:**

[How to: Disable MSDN Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3kzht7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)